# Send POST request in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to send a POST request in Unity, but I can't do that as the function that is supposed to do that is skipped, I'm not sure why. 
I have added logs to have an idea of what happens and "(post json) called" never appears even though the text saying that has gone past the function ((send game played): after postjson) appears in the logs.

```
private static void SendGamePlayed() {
    int incrementedGamePlayed = GetGamePlayed () + 1;
    EventObject anEvent = CreateEvent(EVENT_GAME_PLAYED, incrementedGamePlayed, null, null);

    AbcEvent aAbcEvent = new AbcEvent (bundleID, appToken, anEvent);
    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson (aAbcEvent);

    // test
    Debug.Log("(send game played): " + json);

    PostJSON (json, EVENT_ROUTE);

    Debug.Log ("(send game played): after postjson");

    SetGamePlayed (incrementedGamePlayed);
}


private static IEnumerator PostJSON(string jsonString, string route) {
    // test
    Debug.Log("(post json) called");

    string url = SERVER_URL + route;

    var request = new UnityWebRequest(url, "POST");
    byte[] bodyRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);
    request.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler) new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
    request.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler) new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
    request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    Debug.Log ("(post json) before sending");
    yield return request.Send();
    Debug.Log ("(post json) after sending");

    if (request.error != null) {
        Debug.Log("request error: " + request.error);

    } else {
        Debug.Log("request success: " + request.downloadHandler.text);

    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using Unity's feature for asynchronous operations. To understand the concepts, read up on [generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)) and [Unity coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/351/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Coroutines_26_Yield.html). To run your function, call the `StartCoroutine` function like this:

```
StartCoroutine(PostJSON (json, EVENT_ROUTE));
```

**Edit:**

More specifically: You're creating a [coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) (PostJson) that calls an asynchronous function (Send).

Comment: Yeah..that's exactly what's happening

Comment: I wouldn't call this "asynchronous" but your point is correct.

Comment: The ```UnityWebRequest.Send``` function is asynchronous.

Comment: Not "concurrent", but really "asynchronous" =)